# Recognize the touch event in the moving object

Tags: iphone, core-animation, uitouch

I created a UIImageView dynamically and animating(Moving from one place to another.) in the view.  I wrote touch events and trying to recognize the touch on the image view.  But it is not able recognize the touch event when that image is animating.

But if I touch on the initial place where I added the image view it is recognizing but while animating touch is not working.

```
UIImageView *birdImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(-67, 100, 67, 52)];
birdImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Flying_bird.png"];
birdImage.tag = 1000;
birdImage.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[birdImage setContentMode: UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
[self.view addSubview: birdImage];

[UIView animateWithDuration:10.0  delay:0.0 options: ViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{ 
          birdImage.frame = CGRectMake(547, 100, 67, 52); 
        } completion:nil];

- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
     UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
     NSLog(@"Tag: %d", [[touch view] tag]);
}
```

Please any one could help in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will move image from left to right. and on touching image,your touchesBegan method

calls and you can do anything in your touchesBegan event.

```
 UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
 UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
 imageView.frame = CGRectMake(-1024, 0, 1024, 768);
 [self.view addSubview:imageView];
 [imageView release]; //Your imageView is now retained by self.view
```

You probably need this method -animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:. Replace current method with

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:10.0
                       delay:0.0
                     options: UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                  animations:^{
                      imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768); 
                  }
                  completion:nil];
```

This should enable touches during the animation.

Comment: Hi Mistry, Thanks for your response.  I tried with your code also but not working. I've edited my question please look at the code and let me know where am I doing mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do a hit test on the image view's backing CALayer.  All views contain a CALayer, and a CALayer contains both a model layer and a presentation layer.  The presentation layer is the one you'll need to access:

```
[[imageView.layer presentationLayer] hitTest:point]
```